# JQuery use .css to apply to included page

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm having trouble applying css using `$(".img").css("border", "1px solid black");` when the `img` is in a text file that is being included.

It works fine when the code is included into my `index.html` page, how do I get it to apply the style when the element is in the included page?

Included page:

```
<figure>
  <img src="images/map.gif" alt="Le Mans Circuit Map" class="img">
  <figcaption>Map of the Le Mans Circuit</figcaption>
</figure>
```

It is being included into this div:

```
<div id="tabContent1"></div>
```

EDIT: Updated CSS.

Comment: `.css` takes at most two arguments

Comment: looks like you're calling a class called `.img` not the image tag itself

Comment: I want to set the css to the class `img`

Comment: @Colin747 you have a link?

Comment: Try `$(document).ready(function(){......});`

Comment: @jwoodward http://scmweb.infj.ulst.ac.uk/~B00518833/COM601/assignment_1/index.html#

Comment: @user1090389 it is already in a doc ready function.

Comment: @Colin747 the easiest fix is to just have .img{ border: 1px solid black} in your css, why do it via jQuery?

Comment: Ahh, the link helps. jQuery, JavaScript can only affect elements that already exist. Not sure if this will work, but try putting the script in the `.txt` file. Or, nest the css function under the `$('a[name="#tabContent3"]').click(function () {` after the `.load` function.

Comment: try using `.live()`? you could also just call it by tag, so `img.img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick a function in after the load and place the `.css` in that function.

```
$("#tabContent3").load("test3.txt", function () {
$(".img").css("border", "1px solid black");
});
```

Comment: there does not seem to be a condition to this, why do it in jQuery is my question

put .img{ border: 1px solid black} in your css

Comment: It's being done as a technical exercise hence why I'd rather not put it in the css.

Comment: @user1090389 I've added it to my code if you want to have a look.

Comment: @Colin747 What about a function? .load('test3.txt', function() {$(".img").css("border", "1px solid black");});

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks, if you update your answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".img").css("border", "1px solid black");
```

EDIT

You should clean up your code

jQuery is there to help, your writing too much code

http://jsfiddle.net/peFcx/

Comment: 17 seconds to slow, I guess I shouldn't of included the link the the jQuery site lol.

Comment: It works if I "hard code" the image code into the index page but when I have it as an include it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [jquery css api](http://api.jquery.com/css) notes for details. What you are after is something like this;

```
$( 'img' ).css( 'border', '1px solid black' );
```

Edit:

This code is correct, I guarantee it. If something isn't working it is an error in your implementation of it. I would suggest wrapping your code in a `$( document ).ready( ... )` statement like so;

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( 'img' ).css( 'border', '1px solid black' );
});
```

Now when you say

> How do I get it to apply the style when the element is in the included page?

Do you mean that you are using `.$.fn.append` or something of the like? Because if you are, just run that `$.fn.css` code directly after it

Comment: I'm using `$("#tabContent3").load("test3.txt");` as I said that code works if my image code is put in the index page. It doesn't work when I'm loading the page into the div using `.load`

Comment: If you use the link above you can check my implementation of the code, it is in `common.js`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another CSS applied then you can use this

```
$('.img').css('border','1px black solid !important');
```

If you are loading it through ajax just call it on success callback

I hope this help